# Explain this C++ program

Tags: c++

can anyone explain this Program to me line to line , I realy need to learn this one very soon . thank you .

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100],*p,ch;
    cout<<"Enter A String = ";
    gets(str);
    cout<<"Enter A Character = ";
    ch=getche();
    p=(char *)memchr(str,ch,strlen(str));
    if(p)
        cout<<"\n\n"<<ch<<" is at position = "<<p-str;
    else
        cout<<"\n\n"<<ch<<" Not Found";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's start with the first one. From the very first C++ standard, this was not a standard header. It's `<iostream>`. And this is more C than C++. The only actual C++ is the output.

Comment: thank you for your help and can you tell how should it be only the first one the other will be like it . right ?

Comment: @user3047369 Yes! Get a beginner's tutorial ...

Comment: @user3047369 This is not a legal C++ program. No idea where you got it from but it might be better to learn real C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very short... All the #include means that you can use the resources defined somewhere else, e.g. the "cout" is the name of the standard stream and it is defined in C (or C++) library and it is made available to your program by the header file iostream.h. You can think about it as on interface between your program and some external library or external code.

int main(){

}

This is the entry point of your program - in this case it will be the DOS or console program. It is the standard name of the first function that is called (executed) within your code after the whole program is successfuly compiled, linked and executed. In other words, each line of code (or command) inside the parentheses of the main function will be performed, in order you have written it...

char [100]... is the definition of the field containing 100 items of the char (CHARacter) type. In other words, it can be the text string containing 100 characters at most. The field is stil empty (contains no characters) after this command. Simply it reserves the place for 100 characters in memory.

*p...is the pointer to the the memory location occupied by the char type. It is relevant to the "char" word on the begining of the line. In this case it is only declared, it doesn't point anywhere yet. Also, it can point to the first char of the field of the char type.

ch...it is the declaration (not definition - it doesn't contain any value yet!) of the variable of the char type (again, it is relevant to the "char" on the line begining).

cout<<"Enter A String = ";...This is more complex but in short, the cout is the standard output stream that will write the text string followint the << to the standard output (usually to the screen if not refirected somewhere else).

gets(str);...this command will read all the characters you write and save them into the str field after you press the Enter key. Note that your str field (defined on the first line of the main function) has capacity for 100 items only so your text string can not be longer that that or it will throw some exception or drop your program in the better case...
Moreover, your text string can have only 99 characters because every text string must be ended by the '\0' character that is the 100th character...

cout<<"Enter A Character = ";...again, this will write the text "Enter A Character = " on the standard output stream.

ch=getche();...the getche function will read the character you enter and it will save into the "ch" variable... So now your ch variable will contain the character entered.

p=(char *)memchr(str,ch,strlen(str));...If you remember, the p is the pointer to some memory location. "memchr" is the function that will search for the character given by the second parameter (the "ch" in this case) within the string given by the first character ("str" in your case). The third parameter (strlen(str)) defines the number of characters within the string searched through. In this case, strlen(str) function returns the number indicating the length of the "str" string so the memchr function will search the character you entered (saved inside the "ch" variable) within the whole string str (the string you entered and read by the gets(str) ) function...

Because the memchr function returns the pointer to the void type and you need to save the address of memory location thath holds the character "ch" within the "str" string ("str" field)...and this is the memory place of the "char" type, you need to cast (convert) the void* type to the char* type - (p* is the pointer to the char type - refer to the first line of the main function). This is provided by the (char*) text.

The if-else statement is simply the conditional execution...you can consider it like in natural language. IF something is true then perform the following command ELSE perform something else... So, in your case, if the p pointer is not null (the memchr function found the character "ch" within the "str" string) THEN

cout<<"\n\n"<

...ELSE (IF the first condition IS NOT true => the p pointer is null)

cout<<"\n\n"<

getch();...if you run this program in the command prompt under the Windows OS, this console window will close after the completion of the program. This function waits for the character entered by the keyboard so, i.e. the window will not close until you press the key so you can review the output of your program.

return 0;... this command will ensure that the main function (that has int (integer) type return value) will return the 0 value to the host operating system. Usualy, the 0 value means "everyting is O.K., the program execution was successful. Any other value usualy means that there was some error during execution of the program...

Hope that this eplanations will help you....but as I've mentioned at the beginning - it is very simplified explanation. If you are interested in C/C++ programming, refer to the many tutorials on the web or many books relevant to this topic :-)

Good luck :-)

Comment: thank you for your very helpful answer but can you tell me difference between cin>>str; and gets(str); or cin>>ch; and ch=getche(); .

Comment: cin, cout etc. are STREAMS. You can thing about it as on abbreviations of - "c" + "out" where "c" is the C or C++ and "out" means the "output". The same for "c" + "in" where the "in" means the input. Unlike getch, getche, gets,etc. the streams are more "flexible"...you can use many formating and other manipulators and you can chain them. Standard getch, getche...use totaly different aproach and they are not so "save". For example, the "better" way to put a new line into the cout stream is use of the "endl".

Comment: So you can rewrite your cout<<"\n\n"<<ch<<" is at position = "<<p-str; to somtething like cout << endl << endl << ch << " is at position = ". << p-str; As you see, you can realy chain the output as desired. It is not posssible to explain this here - use your mind and look for the "C streams" on some searching engine. :-) You can find many useful infos here: [link] (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial)/basic_io/) [/link] and on many other tutorials... :-)